# Force QTabBar tabs to stay as small as possible and ignore sizeHint

Tags: python, pyside2, qtabbar

I'm trying to have a `+` button added to a `QTabBar`. There's a [great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20098415/2403000) from years ago, with a slight issue that it doesn't work with `PySide2`. The problem is caused by the tabs auto resizing to fill the `sizeHint`, which in this case isn't wanted as the extra space is needed. Is there a way I can disable this behaviour?

I've tried `QTabBar.setExpanding(False)`, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20014036/2403000) answer, the property is mostly ignored:

> The bad news is that QTabWidget effectively ignores that property, because it always forces its tabs to be the minimum size (even if you set your own tab-bar).

The difference being in `PySide2`, it forces the tabs to be the preferred size, where I'd like the old behaviour of minimum size.

**Edit:** Example with minimal code. The `sizeHint` width stretches the tab across the full width, whereas in older Qt versions it doesn't do that. I can't really override `tabSizeHint` since I don't know what the original tab size should be.

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(100000, super().sizeHint().height())

class Test(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Test, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        tabWidget.setTabBar(TabBar())
        layout.addWidget(tabWidget)

        tabWidget.addTab(QtWidgets.QWidget(), 'this shouldnt be stretched')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = Test()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is it possible to throw together a quick example? I am familiar with pyqt5, but not necessarily pyside.

Comment: Hey, just did the quick example

Comment: Thanks for the example. It really does make it much easier to come up with the solution quickly. I even find myself answering my own problems sometimes when figuring out the exact minimal amount of code to reproduce the issue. As it turns out, pyside and pyqt are drop-in compatible for the most part.

Comment: I use `Qt.py` to deal with any compatibility issues between `PySide`, `PyQt4`, `PySide2` and `PyQt5`, complete lifesaver at work when we still gotta use Python 2 for most things :)

Comment: I'm gonna have to look this over a bit later. Since my answer isn't right, I'm gonna delete for now.

Comment: Alright thanks for your time on it anyway, it's just a little annoying as I'd found an almost perfect solution that `PySide2` broke haha.

Comment: I may have found a satisfactory solution: use a tab itself rather than a push-button as the "+" button. If you  want it aligned right with your tabs aligned left, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37201443/move-two-qt-tabs-to-the-right-leave-rest-to-the-left/37203075) may contain the solution.

Comment: Still on a campsite so will check your answer later, but in response to using a tab, I looked into it last year, if you enable re-ordering tabs, then it's impossible to treat the + tab separately, and putting in your own checks just makes it messy as the visual effect is still there

Comment: The linked solution uses 2 separate TabBars to solve that problem. I further discuss various options in my new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be an easy solution to your problem (see below). Where the linked partial solution calculated absolute positioning for the '+' button, the real intent with Qt is always to let the layout engine do it's thing rather than trying to tell it specific sizes and positions. `QTabWidget` is basically a pre-built amalgamation of layouts and widgets, and sometimes you just have to skip the pre-built and build your own.

example of building a custom TabWidget with extra things across the TabBar:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from random import randint
    
class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #layout for entire widget
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        #top bar:
        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        
        self.tab_bar = QtWidgets.QTabBar()
        self.tab_bar.setMovable(True)
        hbox.addWidget(self.tab_bar)
        
        spacer = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(0,0,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        hbox.addSpacerItem(spacer)
        
        add_tab = QtWidgets.QPushButton('+')
        hbox.addWidget(add_tab)
        
        #tab content area:
        self.widget_stack = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(self.widget_stack)
        self.widgets = {}

        #connect events
        add_tab.clicked.connect(self.add_tab)
        self.tab_bar.currentChanged.connect(self.currentChanged)
        
    def add_tab(self):
        tab_text = 'tab' + str(randint(0,100))
        tab_index = self.tab_bar.addTab(tab_text)
        widget = QtWidgets.QLabel(tab_text)
        self.tab_bar.setTabData(tab_index, widget)
        
        self.widget_stack.addWidget(widget)
        
        self.tab_bar.setCurrentIndex(tab_index)

        
    def currentChanged(self, i):
        if i >= 0:
            self.widget_stack.setCurrentWidget(self.tab_bar.tabData(i))
        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = TabWidget()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

All that said, I think the pre-built [`QTabWidget.setCornerWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#setCornerWidget) may be exactly what you're looking for (set a QPushButton to the upper-right widget). The example I wrote should much easier to customize, but also much more effort to re-implement all the same functionality. You will have to re-implement some of the signal logic to create / delete / select / rearrange tabs on your own. I only demonstrated simple implementation, which probably isn't bulletproof to all situations.

Comment: Cheers, the size hint is required for the `+` button to fit so I can't remove it, I only set it to a high number to demonstrate the issue. Setting the alignment didn't stop the stretching however - https://i.imgur.com/ZBHxuZX.png  (for reference, this is how it looks in `PySide` - https://i.imgur.com/wrGuHej.png)

Comment: @Peter I entirely re-wrote my answer after some additional research. I think the approach of manually hinting the size of the TabBar so that an absolute positioned button fits in the right space is not a sustainable solution. It would seem QTabWidget already has the ability to add custom buttons (or any widget really) to the corners, and I also built an example of writing your own version of TabWidget for greater flexibility.

Comment: Thanks, this does seem more robust, if a little less nice looking. I had to make a few minor changes - move the spacer to after the `+` button, override the `minimumSizeHint` of the tab bar to always return `0` for the width, hide the tab bar when empty. I'll work on implementing it for my existing tool before selecting this answer just to check it all correctly holds up

Comment: Another minor issue I noticed when reimplementing the functionality - using `tabBar.tabAt(point)` works as if there are no `contentsMargins` on the layouts, so these need to be accounted for or removed

Comment: Thanks for all your help anyway, added my final code as an answer if its useful to anyone else

Answer (score 1):

Using the code from Aaron as a base to start on, I managed to implement all the functionality required to work with my existing script:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        """Allow the tab bar to shrink as much as needed."""
        minimumSizeHint = super(TabBar, self).minimumSizeHint()
        return QtCore.QSize(0, minimumSizeHint.height())

class TabWidgetPlus(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    tabOpenRequested = QtCore.Signal()
    tabCountChanged = QtCore.Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self._addingTab = False
        super(TabWidgetPlus, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        # Main layout
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # Bar layout
        self._tabBarLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self._tabBarLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self._tabBarLayout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.addLayout(self._tabBarLayout)

        self._tabBar = TabBar()
        self._tabBarLayout.addWidget(self._tabBar)
        for method in (
                'isMovable', 'setMovable',
                'tabsClosable', 'setTabsClosable',
                'tabIcon', 'setTabIcon',
                'tabText', 'setTabText',
                'currentIndex', 'setCurrentIndex',
                'currentChanged', 'tabCloseRequested',
            ):
            setattr(self, method, getattr(self._tabBar, method))

        self._plusButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('+')
        self._tabBarLayout.addWidget(self._plusButton)  # TODO: Find location to insert
        self._plusButton.setFixedWidth(20)

        self._tabBarLayout.addStretch()

        # Content area
        self._contentArea = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()
        layout.addLayout(self._contentArea)

        # Signals
        self.currentChanged.connect(self._currentChanged)
        self._plusButton.clicked.connect(self.tabOpenRequested.emit)

        # Final setup
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    @QtCore.Slot(int)
    def _currentChanged(self, i):
        """Update the widget."""
        if i >= 0 and not self._addingTab:
            self._contentArea.setCurrentWidget(self.tabBar().tabData(i))

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        """Intercept events until the correct height is set."""
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Show:
            self.plusButton().setFixedHeight(self._tabBar.geometry().height())
            self.removeEventFilter(self)
        return False

    def tabBarLayout(self):
        return self._tabBarLayout

    def tabBar(self):
        return self._tabBar

    def plusButton(self):
        return self._plusButton

    def tabAt(self, point):
        """Get the tab at a given point.
        This takes any layout margins into account.
        """
        offset = self.layout().contentsMargins().top() + self.tabBarLayout().contentsMargins().top()
        return self.tabBar().tabAt(point - QtCore.QPoint(0, offset))

    def addTab(self, widget, name=''):
        """Add a new tab.

        Returns:
            Tab index as an int.
        """
        self._addingTab = True
        tabBar = self.tabBar()
        try:
            index = tabBar.addTab(name)
            tabBar.setTabData(index, widget)
            self._contentArea.addWidget(widget)

        finally:
            self._addingTab = False
        return index

    def insertTab(self, index, widget, name=''):
        """Inserts a new tab.
        If index is out of range, a new tab is appended.

        Returns:
            Tab index as an int.
        """
        self._addingTab = True
        tabBar = self.tabBar()
        try:
            index = tabBar.insertTab(index, name)
            tabBar.setTabData(index, widget)
            self._contentArea.insertWidget(index, widget)

        finally:
            self._addingTab = False
        return index

    def removeTab(self, index):
        """Remove a tab."""
        tabBar = self.tabBar()
        self._contentArea.removeWidget(tabBar.tabData(index))
        tabBar.removeTab(index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import random

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = TabWidgetPlus()

    test.addTab(QtWidgets.QPushButton(), 'yeah')
    test.insertTab(0, QtWidgets.QCheckBox(), 'what')
    test.insertTab(1, QtWidgets.QRadioButton(), 'no')
    test.removeTab(1)
    test.setMovable(True)
    test.setTabsClosable(True)

    def tabTest():
        name = 'Tab ' + str(random.randint(0, 100))
        index = test.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel(name), name)
        test.setCurrentIndex(index)
    test.tabOpenRequested.connect(tabTest)
    test.tabCloseRequested.connect(lambda index: test.removeTab(index))

    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The one difference is if you're using `tabWidget.tabBar().tabAt(point)`, this is no longer guaranteed to be correct as it doesn't take any margins into account. I set the margins to `0` so this shouldn't be an issue, but I also included those corrections in `TabWidgetPlus.tabAt`.

I only copied a few methods from `QTabBar` to `QTabWidget` as some may need extra testing.

Answer (score 0):

Not found anywhere the correct answer on that question, but during experiments came to this conclusion: all attempts to shrink tabs will fail, since no way has been found to set SizeHint of each tab.

But QTabWidget do this by default, so.. why not use it and add some code to handle 'plus tab'?

Simplified example:

```python
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTabWidget, QLabel, QInputDialog


class Tabs(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.prev_tab_index = 0
        self.tab_change_ignore = False

        # Add at least one normal tab
        self.tab_all = QLabel('All')
        self.addTab(self.tab_all, 'All')

        # Access tabs directly, and add 'plus tab' without its widget
        tabs = self.tabBar()
        tabs.addTab('+')
        tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.tab_change)

    def tab_change(self, i):
        # Ignore internal manipulations
        if self.tab_change_ignore:
            return

        # Handle 'plus tab'
        if self.count() - i == 1:
            self.tab_change_ignore = True
            if name := QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Adding tab', 'Enter tab name:')[0]:
                self.insertTab(i, QLabel(name), name)
                self.setCurrentIndex(i)
            else:
                self.setCurrentIndex(self.prev_tab_index)
            self.tab_change_ignore = False
            
        # Handle other tabs
        else:
            self.setCurrentIndex(i)
            self.prev_tab_index = i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = Tabs()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

`prev_tab_index` and `tab_change_ignore` is also used for closable tabs in my project, and I don't rewrite its logic. But everything seems to work as expected.

Also, for provided logic - at least one tab must be added, excepting 'plus tab'!